# How to prove by induction that $3^{3n}+1$ is divisible by $3^n+1$ for $(n=1,2,...)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

So this is what I've tried:
Checked the statement for $n=1$ - it's valid.
Assume that $3^{3n}+1=k(3^n+1)$ where $k$ is a whole number (for some n). Proving for $n+1$: $$3^{3n+3}+1=3^33^{3n}+1=3^3(3^{3n}+1)-26=3^3k(3^n+1)-26=3^3k(3^n+1)-3^3+1=3^3[k(3^n+1)-1]+1$$ and I'm stuck. Any help please?

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Did you devise it? Things like this are not very amenable to a direct proof by induction on $\,n.\,$  That's true even for much simpler cases, e.g. good luck trying to prove that $\,n\!+\!1\mid n^2\!-\!1\,$ by induction on n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true for $n=1$. Assume it holds for $n$, i.e: $3^{3n} + 1 = k(3^n +1)$ then consider $$3^{3(n+1)} +1 = 27 \cdot 3^{3n} + 1 = 27 (3^{3n} +1) - 26 = 27k(3^n +1) - 26$$

Let's get it into a more amenable form $$\begin{equation}3^{3(n+1)} +1 = 9k3^{n+1} + 27k - 26 = 9k(3^{n+1}+1) + 18k - 26 \end{equation} \tag{1}$$

So we want to show that $3^{n+1} + 1$ always divides $18k - 26$ where $$k = \frac{3^{3n} + 1}{3^n + 1} = 3^{2n} - 3^n + 1$$

Equivalently we want to show that $3^{n+1} + 1$ divides $18\cdot 3^{2n} - 18 \cdot 3^n - 8 $. But: $$18\cdot 3^{2n} - 18 \cdot 3^n - 8 = 2(3^{n+1} - 4)(3^{n+1} + 1) \quad \quad (\star)$$

It is then clear that $3^{n+1} + 1$ divides $18k - 26$ since $2(3^{n+1} - 4)$ is an integer.

And hence, since $3^{3(n+1)} + 1$ is the sum of two terms (see $(1)$), each divisible by $3^{n+1} + 1$, where the divisibility holds due to a relation we exploited from the inductive hypothesis, we are done inductively.

---

If $(\star)$ seems a bit magical, simply look at $f(x) = 18x^2 - 18x - 8 = 2(3x-4)(3x+1)$ and substitute in $x = 3^n$.

Comment: Nice! This all looks good to me. Looking back, I now see my main mistake was in not further pursuing the idea, as you did, to show that $3^{n+1}+1$ always divides $18k-26$. Especially nice was your presumable substitution $x=3^n$ when factoring $18x^2-18x-8$ to make the $3^{n+1}+1$ factor shake out, as desired. Can't award the bounty until after 24 hours, but the important deductions are there. Good one!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, I appreciate it. I think the main stumbling block for me was that I needed to work with an explicit expression of $k$ (since it *has* to depend on $n$, otherwise the divisor can just get arbitrarily large) which something I've never done before in an induction divisibility proof. Thanks again!

Comment: This is certainly not perverse: in fact, I think it's quite clever!

Comment: @Strants thank you! :-)

Comment: So the main idea is the use of explicit form of $k$ and the rest is really neat algebra as far as I'm able to understand this.

Answer (score 9):

As an interesting alternative, note that $x^3 +1 = (x+1)(x^2 - x + 1)$, so setting $x = 3^n$ gives $3^{3n} + 1 = (3^n + 1)(3^{2n} - 3^n + 1)$.

Comment: But the OP asks for a proof by induction, which the above is not.

Comment: So basically I write $3^{3n+3}+1$ as $(3^{n+1}+1)(3^{2n+2}-3^{n+1}+1)$, then it follows that $(3^{n+1}+1)(3^{2n+2}-3^{n+1}+1)=k(3^{n+1}+1)$, then I cancel out the $3^{n+1}+1$ term from both sides, and then it leads to $3^{2n+2}-3{n+1}+1=k$ which basically means that that expression yields a whole number, which is always true. Is this a valid induction proof?

Comment: Well, really, as soon as you have $3^{3n +3} = (3^{n+1}+1)(3^{2n+2}-3^{n+1}+1)$, you're done, no need for any of the cancelling. Of course, this means that you haven't used the inductive hypothesis, so it's no longer an actual induction. Are you sure you need to use induction?

Comment: Yeah, I need to use induction strictly.

Comment: This *is* induction in a perverse sort of way: the statement holds for $n=1$, and assuming it holds for $n-1$, the above argument shows the statement holds for $n$ (without using the $n-1$ case).

Comment: @Strants I suppose I should have specified that I did not want a *perverse* use of induction in the bounty commentary. `;-)`

Comment: Well, I've had a go. Not sure if it qualifies as being perverse or not though. :-P